# Where is Sigma.js's sigma.utils.xhr() method?

Tags: javascript, neo4j, sigma.js

Lines 23 and 24 of sigma/plugins/sigma.neo4j.cypher/sigma.neo4j.cypher.js read:

```
sigma.neo4j.send = function(neo4j, endpoint, method, data, callback) {
    var xhr = sigma.utils.xhr(),
```

However, sigma/src/utils/sigma.utils.js contains no reference to that method. I am using a clone of the latest sigma repository. How do I use the neo4j plugin and avoid the error:

```
TypeError: sigma.utils.xhr is not a function
```

'My' code is the default example:

```
    sigma.neo4j.cypher(
        { url: 'xxx', user: 'demo-app', password: 'xxx' },
        'MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN n,r,m LIMIT 100',
        { container: 'graph-container' } ,
        function(s) {
            console.log('Number of nodes :'+ s.graph.nodes().length);
            console.log('Number of edges :'+ s.graph.edges().length);
        }
);
```

Includes are:

```
<script src="sigma/src/sigma.core.js"></script>
<script src="sigma/src/utils/sigma.utils.js"></script>
<script src="sigma/plugins/sigma.neo4j.cypher/sigma.neo4j.cypher.js">
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you did not install all the dependencies using `npm install`. I just cloned and installed Sigma and tried the `sigma.js/examples/load-neo4j-cypher-query.html` and it works fine.

Hope this helps